# Impossible to use a second google account as login (app)

Tags: feature-request, android-app, login

I have two google accounts, one for personal use (the one I'm using on my phone), and another for neutral/professional use (the one I use as my login in Stack Exchange).

My problem is the following: I was trying to use the Stack Exchange app, but I've noted that it is effectively impossible for me to log in due to the fact that it does not gives me the option to choose a second google account to log in (it forces me to use my currently logged account).

I believe this scenario is not uncommon, therefore I would like to know why there is this restriction regarding the app.

Also this question serves as a feature request, if it is indeed impossible for me to log in in my scenario.

Comment: You need to add that second Google account to your device in order to use it to log in to the app. Then it's just "hamburger menu > Settings > Log out" then "Log In > select account".

Comment: While it is indeed possible to do that, this workaround is just too much effort for such a simple task as log in an app.

Comment: \*shrug\* If you have two Twitter accounts and you use the official Twitter app, you need to log out of one to log into the other. Lots of apps do it that way. It seems to me like too much work for not enough gain.

Comment: Well, your Twitter example is different from the Stack Exchange scenario presented. While in twitter's app it is a simple task to log out your twitter account to log in in another, in the Stack Exchange app I have to set up an additional google account to my phone, then log in that account, just to open the Stack Exchange app, and then I would need to log out my google account to log in my true google account when I'm done. Can you spot the difference?